# Image not loading inside the container in flutter, throws an exception instead

Tags: flutter, dart

Made this weather app which changes background image based on the current weather,
but even after editing pubspec.yaml it shows error.
I have stored around 6 images in the images directory, each with the name realted to the current weather

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var loc="";
  late TextEditingController location= TextEditingController();
  var temp;
  var description;
  var currently;
  var humidity;
  var windSpeed;
  Future getWeather(String location) async{
    http.Response response= await http.get(Uri.parse("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$location&units=metric&appid=5e749d88f2df02cacc9be6abf8088531"));
    var results=jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(results);
    setState(() {
      this.temp=results['main']['temp'];
      this.description=results['weather'][0]['description'];
      this.currently=results['weather'][0]['main'];
      this.humidity=results['main']['humidity'];
      this.windSpeed=results['wind']['speed'];
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    this.getWeather(loc);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("images/Weather.jpg"),
              )
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      controller: location,
                       onSubmitted: (String value ){
                         setState(() {
                           loc=location.text;
                         });
                         getWeather(loc);
                       },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "City name",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none
                          )

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        loc=location.text;
                      });
                      getWeather(loc);
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    color: Colors.white,

                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 100,),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    loc!=null?loc:"",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    temp!=null?"$temp°C":loc!=""?"Loading":"Enter City Name",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color:temp!=null?temp>40?Colors.redAccent:temp>=30&&temp<=40?Colors.orangeAccent:Colors.greenAccent:Colors.grey,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 50
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    description!=null?"$description":"",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 70,),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,

                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white10,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(width: 20,),
                        FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.cloud,color: Colors.white,),
                        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                        Text(
                          "Currently",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 18
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                        Text(
                          currently!=null?"$currently":"",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 20,)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,

                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white10,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(width: 20,),
                        FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.water,color: Colors.white,),
                        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                        Text(
                          "Humidity",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 18
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                        Text(
                          humidity!=null?"$humidity%":"",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 20,)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,

                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white10,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(width: 20,),
                        FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.wind,color: Colors.white,),
                        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                        Text(
                          "Wind speed",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 18
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                        Text(
                          windSpeed!=null?"$windSpeed Km/h":"",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 20,)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the pubspec file
Have i added the assets correctly? i did the same thing before but it works but why doesn't it work here?

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/Weather.jpg
```

Comment: add exception which is throwen?

Comment: Did you restart or rebuild app?

Answer (score 0):

try changing this line

```
assets:
    - images/Weather.jpg
```

by doing this, you are ignoring rest of your image files within images directory. Simply use

```
assets:
    - images/
```

it will include all image files automatically.

Comment: Tried this as well, still throws exception

Comment: there should be exactly two tabs (or four whitespaces) before - images/. Also run pub get .